# gradlew assembleRelease failing when using targetCompatibility 1.8

Tags: android, gradle

My command worked perfectly before I changed my targetCompatibility to 1.8, but after the change, I keep having this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Even with `--stacktrace` and `--debug`, no more info is available to me.

This is the command I'm using: `./gradlew assembleRelease`

This is for an Android library, my main application using this library is also using targetCompatibility 1.8, and is building fine with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `JAVA_HOME` that is not correctly set during the command.

Simply using `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) ./gradlew assembleRelease` made the process work.